# Desenvolvimento app com interação pela voz no android studio

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um app onde o usuário vai se comunica com o app por voz,
e como sou novato não sei oque devo usar, gostaria de saber qual a melhor api ou biblioteca? estou usando o android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar funcionalidades fornecidas pelo próprio Android.

Dê uma lida na documentação:

Adicionando Funcionalidades de Voz: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html

E na classe SpeechRecognizer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

Provavelmente já vai te dar uma boa luz.